# C if else condition

Tags: c

In C if i have only one line in the if condition then can i combine it into one line to reduce the size of code. The size of code is long so I intend to take this step to reduce size of code. Should I should I not? Is it a good programming practice?

Comment: can u post a snippet of your code?

Comment: If I understand anything, the reduction will be in the amount of white space and, potentially, in readability.

Comment: what? you aren't so clear. you have a `if` statement with one line, and you want to reduce it to one line?

Comment: I guess you mean omit the `{` and `}` ?

Comment: if(condition == true)\n\t
      do-this;
Can I replace it with
if(condition == true) do-this; ?

Comment: Do whatever the convention says where you are. Spartan Programming convention for example would say: definetly. Others would say: Never.

Comment: Code size means number of instructions used. It doesn't mean that empty space increasing code size.  so there is no difference in your code excepting losing readability. so keep it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if the code is long then it's not good programming practice as that code will not be as readable.

so it's better to use if else syntax to make your code readable

Answer (score 1):

It makes no sense to be concerned about the size of the sources at the point of sacrificing readability, especially since sources are extremely small compared to almost any kind of other data that our computers usually process/store (e.g. the bzipped sourced of the Whole Firefox are 85 MB - smaller than any medium-length video). Also, omitting a newline won't change the compilation times of a millisecond.

So, if you prefer one-line `if`s for your own stylistic reasons it's fine (although it's often frowned upon), but for saving a few bytes it makes no sense at all.

Comment: I am not worried about the compilation times. If i replace a 2 line code with a 1 line code, i save one line. Say if i have 20 such if elses then i save 20 lines.

Comment: @ParthShah: so what? For the compiler whitespace makes no difference, it will emit exactly the same output executable.

Comment: I wanted to combine it on one line only to reduce the size of code, to make the functions look shorter, thus making a long function look shorter. 
Anyways i feel that it is not a good programaming practice so i will stick with the convention style.

Comment: Again, what's the advantage in doing so? The reduction in file size is negligible, you are only cramming more stuff in the same screen at expense of readability, which usually isn't regarded as a good practice (unless you are working on 80x25 ttys, but it's not the 80s anymore...)

Comment: I still feel that "my style" was good. But will stick with the convention so that when someone else reads the code its easier for him/her.